# gnuplot - load script into history

Tags: gnuplot, interactive

I have a few gnuplot commands saved into a text file, gnuplot.txt.  From an interactive session I run

```
load 'gnuplot.txt'
```

and the commands in that script file are executed into the current session setting up a few preconfigured plot parameters.  However those commands are not loaded into the session history.  If I push the up arrow I only get "load 'gnuplot.txt'" on the input line.
Is there a way of loading and running the commands in that file such that they are available in the session history, ie pushing the up arrow will cycle through the commands found inside that text file?

Comment: No, you cannot load a script that way. On Linux you could try starting gnuplot with `gnuplot < gnuplot.txt`, I cannot test at the moment if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the plot command of the imported script into the command history.

```
show plot add2history
```

Use this command after you load the script.